# Condense dataset by unique id

Tags: r, row, unique

I have rows with recurring IDs that I would like to merge. The columns are binaries so I would like to sum them together

Example before:

```
 id      nam1      nam2
  1      1         1
  1      0         0
  2      1         0
  2      0         1
  3      1         1
  3      1         0
```

Example after:

```
id      nam1      nam2
 1      1         1
 2      1         1
 3      2         1
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `aggregate(.~id, df, sum)` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@d.b's answer in comment:

```
aggregate(.~id, df, sum)
```

or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_all("sum")
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id  nam1  nam2
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     1     1
3     3     2     1
```

**Data**

```
df = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), nam1 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), nam2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"nam1", "nam2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Sample data:
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 nam1=c(1,0,1,0,1,1), 
                 nam2=c(1,0,0,1,1,0))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(id)]

id nam1 nam2
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    2    1
```